# Does logging count as a datastore write operation

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Trying to work out what is causing my app to go over the free write quota. The only thing I can think of is we are logging  along site of writing, i.e. Does this count as a write operation:

```
func CheckHistory(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ...
   c.Infof("Some log stuff")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer is no.  Write is only write to datastore.

Now to try and fix your problem.... Is it the index write quota you keep on busting?  this can easily get problematic if you're not careful with how you build your indexes.  Because as far as I know, and as far as is told [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Logs), no reason for your logs to take any kind of write.